# Docker Tutorial Error

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Trying to run this [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#build-the-app)  but getting error after running the command `docker build -t friendlyhello .`

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint affectionate_hodgkin (4bb235d6cfe9b42185ff3ac8be2ee94b99ed430f357448a2f396be3e2dc00e27): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:4000:tcp:172.17.0.2:80: input/output error.
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check thread https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/issues/839.

Pretty late I know, but I solved this issue by running the following:

docker stop $(docker ps -a -q); docker rm $(docker ps -a -q); docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true)

docker network rm $(docker network ls -q)

sudo lsof -nP | grep LISTEN

sudo kill -9 1548